# problem to adjust outermost-margin of the page

Tags: css

There appears to be about a 4px margin at the outer-edge of the outer-div and the Body.  Between the Yellow Div and the Blue Div. This is between the top and left side of the outermost div and the Body Div.

The outer-div (global-wrap) has its width=100%

Here is the CSS:

```
body
{
    /*background: url("/images/damask-back.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 #423624;*/
    background: url("/images/blueback1.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /*height: 50%;*/
}
#global-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 925px;*/
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*margin: 10px auto;*/
}
#top-wrap {
    height: 112px;    
    background-color: Yellow; 
}
#head-logo {
    /*background: url("/images/logo2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
    background-color: Green;
    height: 112px;
    width: 176px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="global-wrap">
    <div id="top-wrap">
        <div id="head-logo"><a href="/"></a></div>          
    </div>
    <div id="global-inner" >  
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are aware that your `form` tag is not closed?

Comment: sorry forgot to post that, its in there

Comment: also, none of your divs is Blue, do you mean the Green one? And `#top-wrap` should have `position:relative` for `head-logo` to position itself relative to it. Absolute positioning is relative to the first parent with `position` set differently from the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - DEMO: http://jsbin.com/eyeto5

```
* { margin:0; padding:0 }
body
{
    /*background: url("/images/damask-back.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 #423624;*/
    background: url("/images/blueback1.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /*height: 50%;*/
}
/* .... */
```

at the top of your CSS should do the trick;

Comment: would this be in the body div?

Comment: Yea it doesnt let me check it right away, I always have to wait 5 minutes. Thanks again Dude!